# How to read a csv file and convert it into objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, csv

Hi i am reading the file from the local through filereader api. after reading the file i to convert them into javascript objects.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> JSon Parsing </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"
</head>
<body>

   <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" onchange="readFile()">


   <script type="text/javascript">
      function readFile(){
         var file = document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(evt){
             var resultText = evt.target.result;
             console.log(resultText);
        }
        var newFile = file.slice(0,5000);
        reader.readAsText(newFile);             
      }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The ouput should like below

```
{
    "policyID": 119736,
    "statecode": "FL",
    "county": "CLAY COUNTY",
    "eq_site_limit": 498960,
    "hu_site_limit": 498960,
    "fl_site_limit": 498960,
    "fr_site_limit": 498960,
    "tiv_2011": 498960,
    "tiv_2012": 792148.9,
    "eq_site_deductible": 0,
    "hu_site_deductible": 9979.2,
    "fl_site_deductible": 0,
    "fr_site_deductible": 0,
    "point_latitude": 30.102261,
    "point_longitude": -81.711777,
    "line": "Residential",
    "construction": "Masonry",
    "point_granularity": 1
  },
  {
    "policyID": 448094,
    "statecode": "FL",
    "county": "CLAY COUNTY",
    "eq_site_limit": 1322376.3,
    "hu_site_limit": 1322376.3,
    "fl_site_limit": 1322376.3,
    "fr_site_limit": 1322376.3,
    "tiv_2011": 1322376.3,
    "tiv_2012": 1438163.57,
    "eq_site_deductible": 0,
    "hu_site_deductible": 0,
    "fl_site_deductible": 0,
    "fr_site_deductible": 0,
    "point_latitude": 30.063936,
    "point_longitude": -81.707664,
    "line": "Residential",
    "construction": "Masonry",
    "point_granularity": 3
  },
```

I have tried many parser but the ouput is in different from the below ouput.plz somebody help how i can achieve the below ouput

Comment: If you are comfortable using third party library, i'd recommend using http://papaparse.com/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/barney/7vpAJ/

Hopefully it will do the job, even better give you an idea on how to implement your own script!

Checkout the following function in the fiddle, it'll point you in the right direction

`function csvToArray(csvString){`